# Ansible/Jinja: condition with an undefined statement

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to iterate over all hosts and generate config file for hosts that are not contained in group `somegroup`:

```
{% for host in groups.all if host not in groups['somegroup'] %}
```

But if somegroup does not exist, it fails (argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable).

How do I write this correctly to avoid two different for cycles:

```
{% if groups['somegroup'] is defined %}
{% for host in groups.all if host not in groups['somegroup'] %}
...
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
{% for host in groups.all %}
...
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [`default`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#default) filter:

`{% for host in groups.all if host not in groups['somegroup'] | default([]) %}`

Comment: Worked as charm. Thanks