# Ansible: is it possible to Jinja2 filter the content picked up by lookup()?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I'm sending a REST API query using Ansible `uri` module. The body content is picked up from a file:

```
body: "{{ lookup('file',mp_config_path + item.file) }}"
```

There are some variables in my file - is it possible to tell ansible to run Jinja2 filters on it before sending it to the `uri` module?

Answer (score 2):

And how about using [`template` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html#more-lookups)?

```
body: "{{ lookup('template',mp_config_path + item.file) }}"
```

or:

```
- uri:
    body: "{{ item }}"
    # other parameters
  with_template: "{{ mp_config_path + item.file }}"
```

Comment: Speed of light! :-D

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Getting better at fast typing. Btw, I've just learnt that the template lookup does not handle `{{ ansible_managed }}`.

Comment: I missed this one ;-) Thanks!

Comment: I don't want to nitpick, but you have [several questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36989167/2947502) to which you added "thank you"-notes without accepting the answers. If an answer works for you, you should click the "accepted"-mark so that it doesn't appear in unanswered questions anymore. It will also increase your reputation a bit.